# What are some good sql databases for home Vista computer?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have been trying for a long time to get SQL Server Express on my computer to practice my C#/SQL with and I still haven't gotten it to work.

Are there other programs I can use to setup an SQL database to practice with?  If so, which are the best ones for Vista?

EDIT: 
To be clear I am not new to SQL programming, I just haven't done any in a while and want to stay fresh.  So I would like something that has most of the features of forms of SQL I would use professionally.

Comment: Which version of SQL Express can't you get to work? What version of Vista? Home, Premium, Ultimate...? And what problems are you having, can you link to the MSDN threads you mentioned/commented on GregD's post?

Comment: here you go: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/b8086e0e-5787-4ab7-acff-9ef758a6b9e8/

Comment: btw, Juniordeveloper.net returns an error: Looks like someone didn't set up their blogengine.net successfully. :-/

Comment: Gortok, whose site is JuniorDeveloper.net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL or Postgresql are both full fledged DB's and good for education/experimentation. You can also check out Oracles free version.

Comment: Since PostgreSQL supports a broader part of and adheres more to the SQL standard, maybe it should be mentioned first, especially from the educational point of view. :-)  (Seriously, I've had a hard time to get over some bad old MySQL habits)

Comment: I can use PostgreSQL with C#.NET?

Comment: -1 for MySQL.  Although the latest version can finally be considered a RDBMS it's peculiarities still mitigate it's use as a generic example database

Answer (score 3):

What aren't you getting to work for Sql Express.  It works on Vista.  I use it on a daily basis.  It no longer comes standard with a "northwind" database, but you an download the AdventureWorks DB.  Can you be more specific about "I still haven't gotten it to work"?

I've also heard good things about [firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)

Although I still believe that C# and SQL Express is the best way to go.

Comment: I've had trouble installing it.  I have been asking the folks on msdn.com to help me and it just hasn't gotten anywhere, so rather than wait around I figured I would ask if there was some easier option.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It was a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: Maybe they didn't like the AdeventureWorks DB?

Comment: I've been running SQL Express 2008 just fine on Vista. Maybe it's a problem with your version of vista? I'm running ultimate 64 with sql 2008 express x64 and it's running flawlessly.

Comment: Can we trade computers? hehe.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is good if you need something fast, small and powerful... its a fast download also.

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

[SQLite with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express generally should be the natural choice for practice with .NET and C#.

If you have no prior experience in working with SQL Server and its Express version one most confusing thing is that SQL Server Express is not installed as default instance, but as SQLEXPRESS instance. So you have to use "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS" in your connection string.

In case you can not overcome issues with SQL Express you can try [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), but you will need to download and use [.NET Data Provider for Postgres](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/references.html).

Answer (score 1):

Both Oracle and IBM offer offer versions of their flagship databases for free in a similar manner to SQL Server Express.  Both are excellent products if you wish to play with a 'real' database system.

[Oracle 10g Express](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html)

[IBM DB2 Express](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/)

Postgres is also well worth considering as it is also a 'real' relational database, having originally started as the much respected Ingres RDBMS in the 1980s.  However Postgress until recently was Unix-based and I've never found it particularly reliable installing on Windows.

Personally I would not recommend MySQL for your scenario - although the latest edition can finally be described as a RDBMS having evolved from what really was a collection of flat files with a limited SQL query interface it's peculiarities probably mitigate against it's use as a learning tool unless you are actually focused on MySQL.

There are a number of other less popular RDMSs you could consider.  [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) has always been something of a favourite of mine as I used to code a lot of Delphi, and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a joy to work with in many circumstances.  It's also a pity you cannot use SQL Server Express as the SQL Server product range is simply the most solid product Microsoft produces and usually my database of choice on anything but the smallest, largest or most unsual installations

Comment: If you use Oracle or DB2 (or MySQL), I recommend the freeware TOAD (Tool for Oracle Application Developers :D) at http://toadsoft.com. I don't work for them, but seriously, it is a lot better than PHPMyAdmin!

Answer (score 1):

I preferr Firebird its a madure BD and its O.S. very stable btw.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/

and try ibexpert for manager this bd.

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/

Answer (score 0):

[Vista DB](http://www.vistadb.net/) is quite a nice lightweight managed flatfile database (not related to Windows Vista).

Comment: Why was this voted down? I'd understand if it's due to it being a brief post, but the one about SQLite has been voted up and that's no different...

Answer (score 0):

For something very simple look at [sqlite](http://sqlite.org) It supports most SQL syntax and stores it's database in a single file so has very little setup. You'll need an ado.net data provider for it which you can find [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) Although it isn't a good choice for multi user systems with lots of data it should be fine for an introduction to database programming.